# Why adding \hsize0pt creates extra line?

Tags: line-breaking

Consider the following test:

```
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\setbox0=\vbox{\hfuzz10000pt \hskip0pt a-b}
\showbox0
\setbox0=\vbox{\hsize0pt \hfuzz10000pt \hskip0pt a-b}
\showbox0
\end
```

The first `\showbox` gives:

```
> \box0=
\vbox(6.94444+0.0)x469.75499
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 435.86607fil
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
..\glue 0.0
..\tenrm a
.......
```

The second one gives:

```
> \box0=
\vbox(24.0+0.0)x0.0
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty 150
.\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
.\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x0.0
..\tenrm a
.......
```

So, adding `\hsize0pt` creates this:

```
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty 150
.\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
```

and the `\glue 0.0` (i.e., the `\hskip0pt`) disappears. Why?

Comment: The `\hskip0pt` is a possible breakpoint. If `\hsize0pt`, TeX will take every possible breakpoint (because the line is always full), so TeX also breaks at the breakpoint at `\hskip0pt`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I used `\hskip0pt` during my experiments with hyphenation, because hyphenation is tried only after a glue. Now I see that it would be better to use `\ `.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger oops, `\ ` does not work either... How do I get rid of that extra line?

Comment: If you add `\leavevmode\nobreak` before the `\hskip`, TeX is not allowed to break there.